# Hibernate, JPA, não salva os novos dados no banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, aplicação-web, jpa

Tenho uma aplicação Java Spring MVC, com Hibernate e JPA e interface HTML.

Tenho dois formulários que dependem da classe CadernoCadastrados e seus atributos.

No primeiro formulário eu insiro os dados de um novo Caderno, salvo no banco e é criado um novo ID para esse registro.

Quando faço uma pesquisa, no caso numeroID=44, é exibido o segundo formulário, que vêm com alguns campos do primeiro formulário já preenchidos, mas desabilitados, e campos adicionais da classe Caderno habilitados para edição. Ou seja, nesse segundo formulário eu só vou adicionar mais informações ao mesmo registro que foi adicionado pelo primeiro formulário:

O problema é que quando clico no botão "Salvar" do segundo formulário, ele não salva os novos dados inseridos no segundo formulário no banco de dados.

Classe CadernosCadastrados.

@Entity
public class CadernosCadastrados implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private Long numeroID;
private String numeroCaderno;
private String cras;
private String dataRecebido;
private String recebidoPor;
private String avaliadoPor;
@Column(length = 2000)
private String observacoes;
private String codigoFamiliar;
private String nis;
private String data;
private String cpf;
private String rg;
private String ctps;
private String caixa;
private String cadernos;
private String certidaoNascimento;
private String fichaExclusao;
private String fichaAveriguacao;
private String suplementar;
private String suplementarDois;
private String entrevistador;
private String responsavelFamiliar;
private String pendenciaDocumentacao;
private String pendenciaFormulario;
private String pendenciaAssinatura;  
public String status;
```

Método alterar que é disparado ao clicar no botão "Salvar" do segundo formulário:

```
@RequestMapping("alterar")
public String alterar(CadernosCadastrados objeto, Long numeroID, Model model) {

    List<CadernosCadastrados> cadernos = daoCadernosCadastrados.listar();

    daoCadernosCadastrados.alterar(objeto);
    //if(daoCadernosCadastrados.limpar(objeto )) {; 


    return "public/sucessos";
```

}

Método alterar na classe DaoCadernoCadastrados, que é chamado pelo método alterar que mostrei anteriormente:

```
public void alterar(CadernosCadastrados objeto) {

    entityManager.merge(objeto);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu usaria um repository extendo do JpaRepository<>. 
Exemplo da classe que fiz:

```
@Repository
public interface PessoaFisicaRepository extends JpaRepository<PessoaFisica, Long> {

}
```

E no service fiz:

```
@Service
public class PessoaFisicaService {

          ** vários outros métodos **

     public PessoaFisica atualizar(PessoaFisica pessoaFisicaJson) {

            PessoaFisica pessoaFisicaBD = buscar(pessoaFisicaJson.getId());
            try {
                atualizarDados(pessoaFisicaBD, pessoaFisicaJson);
                pessoaFisicaBD = pessoaFisicaRepository.save(pessoaFisicaBD);
            } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException erro) {
                throw new ExcecaoDeIntegridadeDeDados("A integridade dos dados fornecidos estão corrompidos e/ou repetidos. Por favor, verifique-os e tente novamente");
            }
            return pessoaFisicaBD;
        }

     private void atualizarDados(PessoaFisica pessoaFisicaBD, PessoaFisica pessoaFisicaJson) {

            if (pessoaFisicaJson.getNome() != null) {
                pessoaFisicaBD.setNome(pessoaFisicaJson.getNome());
            }
            **outros métodos**
    }

     public PessoaFisica converteDeDto(PessoaFisicaDto pessoaFisicaDto) {

     PessoaFisica pessoaFisica = new PessoaFisica(pessoaFisicaDto.getAtivo(), pessoaFisicaDto.getIdEmpresa().. outros getters e setters

}
```

E por fim no meu resource fiz:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/clientes/pf")
public class PessoaFisicaResource {
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> atualizar(@Valid @RequestBody PessoaFisicaDto pessoaFisicaDto, @PathVariable Long id) {
        PessoaFisica pessoaFisica = pessoaFisicaService.converteDeDto(pessoaFisicaDto);
        pessoaFisica.setId(id);
        pessoaFisica = pessoaFisicaService.atualizar(pessoaFisica);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Meu DTO

```
@Getter  // lombok
@Setter  //lombok
public class PessoaFisicaDto implements Serializable {
private Long id;
@NotNull(message = "O campo ativo é obrigatório")
@Min(value = 0, message = "Digite 0 para inativo ou 1 para ativo")
@Max(value = 1, message = "Digite 0 para inativo ou 1 para ativo")
private Byte ativo;
@NotNull(message = "O campo id empresa é obrigatório")
   **vários outros atributos
```

}

Como funciona?
Envio um JSON para o endpoint definido, nesse caso: /api/clientes/pf/{id}
O resource trata a requisição, transformando DTO em Model, com o metodo converteDeDTO. Depois chama o metodo atulizar e por fim faz o build do responseEntity.

Comment: Cara... fazer tudo na mão é da idade da pedra. Ou maven ou gradle. Estude um dos dois, ou caso já saiba, vá com o que tem mais facilidade. Eu uso ambos, mas prefiro o Maven por questões pessoais. Para criar aplicações spring, utilize o https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Ótima notícia. Eu não enviei nada pois estou bem atribulado na empresa.

Comment: Consegui resolver, o que eu fiz peguei os dados do primeiro formulario e trouxe no segundo formulario com os dados desabilitados mais preenchidos mudei no metodo alterar que estava com persist, para merge, assim o ID não foi alterado e com isso salvei os novos dados. no mesmo ID.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está bem confuso, vamos começar pelo serviço "alterar", nele vc faz um `if (objeto.equals(objeto))`, isso não faz sentido algum, vc está comparando algo com ele mesmo, então recomendo remover essa linha ou colocar uma validação que faça sentido. Logo abaixo vc chama uma listagem que não faz nada `List<Caderno> cadernos = dao.listar();`. Depois vemos uma implementação do seu DAO com um método que altera seu objeto caderno,  nele vc recebe como parâmetro a classe `Caderno` e tem um `if` que sempre vai ser falso pois vc sempre passa o `id` como `null`, pois está da seguinte forma `Integer id = null; if (id != null)...`.

Comment: Adriano, então este if do obejto.equals, eu faço ele porque tenho um atributo na classe Caderno chamado "Status" ele esta como String, há nao ser eu passar ele para boolean, por isto este if, este List que faço é para chamar a lista dos dados inseridos, Já no DAO eu tive que colocar este null, porque como coloquei ID, no find ele me pediu para iniciliazar á única opção foi null, já que eu não estou passando o parametro id, no alterar, porque se eu nao criar uma variavél com id e nao incializar ela, não tem jeito fica com erro, já o IF com id != null é para tirar o nullpointer, entendeu.